# Eclipse merge issue with Android (Java) project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I am using Eclipse + Subversion for Android development. I used to create a free version of my apps with ads, and another one payed without them, so I kept them in two separate branches on subversion.

The problem I have found is that as these are two different app for Google Play and other markets, they must have different package names. So I have, for example:

com.package.game
com.package.gamefree

When I do some changes on the free version of the game and want to merge them with subversion into the payed branch, I found myself in a trouble because source files for the free game are below com/package/gamefree and for payed under com/package/game

I ended up doing a "manual" merge, making a diff of source file by source file, but I also have to check those files that have been added into another directories and those that has been deleted. A waste of time.

So, is there any manner to make subversion know that com/package/game in one branch is the "same" directory than com/package/gamefree in the other?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a bit in deep, I found that my better chances was just two:

- Using ANT in anny manner that automatizes the switch between free and payment versions at building time.
- Using an Android Library project shared between two versions.

I have seen that most of the people using ANT were doing it some time ago by the lack of another option, but since there is Android Library projects on Eclipse/ADT this is the preferred way for this kind of things. Even in the development docs of Android, says:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

> If you are creating an application that exists in both free and paid versions. You move the part of the application that is common to both versions into a library project. The two dependent projects, with their different package names, will reference the library project and provide only the difference between the two application versions.

This seems to be the best way for me also because I have never used ANT and given the library option there is no reason for learning it.

So I have done that way: my project is splited now into MyGameCore that is the library project with all common files to both MyGameFree and MyGamePay projects, that now just have the minimal classes needed to have a different main package name so Google Play knows they are different applications, plus the raw assets folder that according to Google Docs cannot be moved to the library. Anyway these are binary files that I simply copy from one version to another when they are changed, that is not very often.

So from now on, most of the time I just need to work on the MyGameCore project and the changes done have inmediate effect on both MyGameFree and MyGamePay projects without needing to merge branches.

This will save me A LOT of time and I will use it on my further projects from the very first code line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but maybe you could have the free app on the `trunk` in the `com.package.gamefree` package.

On the branch you could have the other importing the one developed on the trunk as a dependency lib, and wrap it around with launcher class which is packaged under `com.package.game`, adding the license stuff...

This way you'll only have to modify the code once, and build 2 apps.

Comment: Not bad suggestion at all, but it needs some work before testing. I will give it a try this week and come back with the results. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure no problem, and yes I'm aware of its roughness but as I've said, I'm just guessing :). BTW if you need an automated process to suit this kind of building, you can take a look at the Jenkins continuous integration server http://jenkins-ci.org. It's open source and it allows you to create build jobs which depends on others, and combined with maven you get it all in one shot. Also continuous integrations rules.

Comment: Ok, I am working on this right now and I have found the first major problem. I have moved all files from com.package.gamefree to com.package.gameshared but the main activity, so I would have near everything into com.package.gameshared and just the main activity on com.package.gamefree and com.package.game in each case. But the problem is that the R file for resources is generated within the same package than the main activity, that's stored on the AndroidManifest.xml file, and I cannot change that since it will be used by the market to identify apps as different.

Comment: being more specific, the problem is that I need to import com.package.game[free].R on each file under com.package.gameshared, so I will still need to keep that reference distinct in each branch when merging them. :-|

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance :). I'm not familiar with the android build proces, hence neither with `R files` so I'm not sure I understand. I take it R is a class dealing with resources? What needs to be different in the resources? Can't you define a skeleton `R class` using java generics (or maybe abstract) and have 2 actual implementations for each of the projects?

Comment: R is a class used to refer resources on an Android project, such as strings or bitmaps (so called "drawables"). It is generated automatically by ADT when the project is Build and always put into the app main package defined on the Android manifest file. It contains only static final constants, so that approach is not possible. I have read about using ANT creating an script to copy R class to actual package when it is build, or creating an Android library project with all them common code used by free and payment versions. Will keep you informed.